# Python Requests - Login to Vimeo.com

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, vimeo

I have an account at Vimeo.com and am trying to figure out how to log in using the Python Requests package. Here are my initial observations:

1. Logging in is done via a post request to https://vimeo.com/log_in?ssl=0&iframe=0&popup=0&player=0&product_id=0 and requires an email, password, action, service, and token to be passed as body data
2. The token for the post request appears to be different from the xsrft token but I'm not able to get either as the token appears to be generated via javascript and only valid for each session (though it isn't clear)
3. Cookies are necessary

Here is some initial code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://vimeo.com/log_in?ssl=0&iframe=0&popup=0&player=0&product_id=0'
payload = {'email': 'some@email.com',
           'password': 'privatepassword',
           'action': 'login',
           'service': 'vimeo',
           'token': '?????'
          }
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, allow_redirects=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
```

I can't figure out how to get the correct token for the post request and whether the token is associated with the `vuid` or `xsrft` token.

Comment: Did you find the way to generate the xsrft token?